# rails environment shows test while started in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
 rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.1.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

using pry to debug:

```
[1] pry(#<ProductsController>)> Rails.env
=> "test"
```

What might be the reason? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $ rails c -e development 
   Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.3)
   2.0.0-p481 :001 > Rails.env
   => "development" 
   2.0.0-p481 :002 >
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew about this. The thing is I want to start rails server in dev mode y default without specifying env mode. More, Thin shows it is started in dev mode, why it shows test in debugging? That is my problem.

Comment: You can restart the console `rails c`, Is that in your case it's `Loading test environment` ??

Comment: It's not the console I have problem with, can't you read the question? I am starting the rails server.. and it shows `starting in development`.

Comment: First code snippet is okay, I'm talking about second code snippet. i.e; where you checking `pry(#<ProductsController>)> Rails.env` then is it not in `rails c`

Comment: right, but the second snippet I mentioned it's from using pry and I am debugging inside a rails controller. If I start rails console and run `Rails.env` I get the proper environment response.